# render apex:image with multiple conditions

Tags: visualforce, images, rendered

In my Visualforce, I want to show a traffic red light or green light base on some condition. Below you find my code:

```
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(OR(oldCrashesList.OCTO_Closure_Reason_Text__c == 'Customer contacted by phone: false alarm',oldCrashesList.OCTO_Validated_By_OTP__c == 'Not Validated'),true,false )}">
<apex:image value="{!$Resource.redligth}" />
</apex:outputpanel >
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(oldCrashesList.OCTO_Closure_Reason_Text__c !='Customer contacted by phone: false alarm',true,false)}" >
<apex:image value="{!$Resource.greenlight}" />    
</apex:outputpanel>
```

The problem is that both images are shown in my VF page and I don't understand why.The rendered conditions are opposite of each other.

Comment: The first one includes an `OR` so they are not exact opposites.

Comment: Right, thank you Keith. I need the OR operator in the first output panel so I think that I have to use the same contions but negative, in the second output panel to obtain the exact opposite.Is it right in your opinion Keith?

Comment: Probably clearest to just wrap the first `IF(OR(...))` in a NOT for the second case i.e. `NOT(IF(OR(...)))`.